# Proving quasiconvexity of $x^3 + y^3$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry, non-convex-optimization

I was studying quasiconvex functions, and suddenly I have stumbled upon the function $f(x,y)= x^3+y^3$.

Is it quasiconvex? From the graph it seems like.

Comment: can you describe the graph that you are looking at perhaps? include any attempt in your post.

Comment: actually I made a mistake, I was checking the super level set, i.e. S'(β)={(x,y) | xy≥β} . I tried to visualize this set in R² by fixing β , and it definitely seemed like a convex set as this set gives the upper portion of a rectangular hyperbola. So my question should be is the function quasiconcave? but anyway Roman Chokler has already given a logic which disproves my observation. So I am confused what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not quasiconvex nor is it quasiconcave.

In general, for $a,b,c>0$ and $a>b$, consider local extrema of $x^3+y^3$ along the line $ax+by=c$. substituting the constraint gives us a cubic in $x$ and cubics of a real variable always have range $\mathbb{R}$. The cubic you get will always have two distinct critical points, a local max, and a local min, and so it is not quasiconvex or quasiconcave. Therefore, picking two points with appropriate $x$ on such a line will violate the definitions of both quasiconvexity and quasiconcavity for $f$.

Comment: How did you come up with a>b ? Can you please tell me what is the intution behind that condition?

Comment: also the answer is brilliant. thanks a lot sir.